# Installing ActiveMQ in Karaf

Tags: macos, activemq-classic, karaf

I am trying to install ActiveMQ in Karaf. I did see one answer about an error and I did follow up with the answers for the question. I tried to add the "latest" version of ActiveMQ but no luck.

```
karaf@root()> feature:install jms
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add activemq
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/LATEST/xml/features
karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-broker
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-web-console; type=karaf.feature;  version=5.12.0.SNAPSHOT [caused by: Unable to resolve activemq-web- console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [activemq-web-  console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity;  osgi.identity=org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console; type=osgi.bundle; version="[5.12.0.SNAPSHOT,5.12.0.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by:  Unable to resolve org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT:  missing requirement [org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet.resources)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))"]]
```

To help anybody in answering, I want to add, I did make sure my Karaf is working fine. I made sure of that by adding Camel and then running a sample application. The application ran fine, log generated fine in the "bin/data" folder.
Any pointer would help. I am yet to be seasoned in using Karaf so if you know any forum or mail list for Karaf, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253681/install-activemq-in-apache-karaf-4-0-0-m2

Comment: @ClausIbsen the problem explained in that question isn't exactly same as in my question and besides the answer there isn't accepted because that isn't helpful for either of the questions.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be problems with LATEST activemq from time to time.

I tried Karaf 4.0.6 with activemq/LATEST -> same error.

On Karaf 4.0.6 activemq 5.14.0 works:

```
feature:repo-add activemq 5.14.0
feature:install activemq
```