# Install ActiveMq in Apache Karaf 4.0.0.M2

Tags: osgi, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I'm trying to Install ActiveMQ in Karaf 4.0.0M2.

But it always fails with an error. Please see console below. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
karaf@root()> feature:install jms
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add activemq
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/LATEST/xml/features
karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-broker
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-web-console
; type=karaf.feature; version=5.12.0.SNAPSHOT [caused by: Unable to resolve activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT: missing req
uirement [activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console; type=o
sgi.bundle; version="[5.12.0.SNAPSHOT,5.12.0.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.activ
emq.activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi
.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet.resources)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))"]]
karaf@root()>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the no web feature. - I think its called -noweb or no webconsole or something like that

```
feature:install activemq-broker-noweb
```

The ActiveMQ web console does not support karaf 4.

You can try installing hawtio if you want a web console for ActiveMQ, and other Java stuff which hawtio can do

- http://hawt.io/

Comment: Did not work for me:
  
karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-broker-noweb
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-broker-noweb;...

Comment: As said ActiveMQ does not yet support Karaf 4. Also Karaf 4 is not GA yet its a milestone release. Use older version of Karaf such as 3 or 2.4.

Comment: Agreed, Claus, sorry I wasn't more clear, just wanted to state that unfortunately activemq-broker-noweb doesn't work with 4.0.0M2 either (since it was suggested as a possibility).  I'm personally testing now with 3.0.3.  Thanks for your continued and immense help over the years!